# Unsupported operation: _newZLibDeflateFilter, what is this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

This is getting passed back from my exception. This only occurs on web, on ios and android it works perfectly.

Any insight on how to correct this or point me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide more information about what you tried, when it happened, so that we can try to replicate it in that context.

Answer (score 2):

`_newZLibDeflateFilter` means that you are using `GZipCodec()` which related to `dart:io` library that's currently [doesn't support flutter web](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/dart-io-library.html), in order to decompress your http response you can use [archive package](https://pub.dev/packages/archive)

include the package in your YAML file

```
dependencies:
  archive: ^3.3.2
```

and use `GZipDecoder()` that's included in the package instead of `dart:io`              `GZipCodec()`

```dart
import 'package:archive/archive_io.dart';
```

```dart
String responseBodyDecompressed = utf8.decode(
    GZipDecoder().decodeBytes(response.bodyBytes) //decompression
    );
```